# how to convert back resized channel to image

Tags: python, image, resize

I am dealing with an image. I resized it by flattening each channel and picking one every 10 points as following. (I did this way since I should calculate the point cloud based on RGBD and want to reduce the computation time).

```
I = np.array(Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB'))
I_flat_r = I[:,:,0].flatten()[0:-1:10]
I_flat_g = I[:,:,1].flatten()[0:-1:10]
I_flat_b = I[:,:,2].flatten()[0:-1:10]
```

However, I don't know how to convert it back to an image again. Could any one give some hints?

Comment: Be aware that sampling an image that way will result in aliasing, unless the original image was extremely blurry to begin with.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It duplicated several same images. I wonder whether there is any methods to fill the holes caused by [0:-1:10] if I still want to keep the original shape of image?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and then reshape it

```
new_x_size = int(I.shape[0]/10)
new_image = np.concatenate((I_flat_r, I_flat_g, I_flat_b), axis=0)
new_image - new_image.reshape((new_x_size, -1, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, it duplicated several same images instead of one complete image.